# How to make a list of links that dynamically updates from a Database?

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am re-developing my website in ASP.NET 5, with MVC 6 and EntityFramework 7. It is a reference website for LEGO Collectors. I am Trying to, on the "browse the database" home page, have a list of all years that products have been released. I have developed one, but I am trying to figure out how to link to each year View in the "Browse" Controller, and have the link names be the years.

Example:

- 2014
- 2015
- 2016

Is what my page is like now, but dynamic. I want these years to appear as links, and link to the section for each year in the Controller.

Here is my current code:

```
<ul class="browse-years">
@foreach (var item in Model.Select(c => c.YearFrom).Distinct()) { 
    <li>@item</li>
}
```

I hope you can help with this. Thank you.

Jarod

Owner of UltimateBrickReference.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your LI element, use an Html.ActionLink helper to create your link:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink(item.ToString(), "ListYear", new { thisYear = item })</li>
```

This will render HTML that looks like this:

```
<li><a href="/Home/ListYear?thisYear=2016">2016</a></li>
```

The first argument is the link text; if item is not a string, then it must be converted to one. The second argument is the controller action that you want to get control when the user clicks the link. The third argument is an object containing a property that stores the value the year (or item or item.year or whatever), so the controller knows which year to display data for.

Then, in your controller, write an action that gets the data to be displayed and transfers control to a view that will display that data. It will start out something like this:

```
 public ViewResult ListYear(object year)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

You can add the code to extract the year from the object, retrieve it from the database, and then pass it to a view that you will create to display the passed data.

Comment: in asp.net 5 mvc 6 we use Tag Helpers and no Html Helpers

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<li><a asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Display"  asp-route-id="@ViewBag.ProductId">@item</a></li>
```

this will give you the following:

```
<a href="/Product/Display/1">View Details</a>
```

So change the  asp-controller, asp-action and asp-route-id based on what you want. If you want any help please let me know

Comment: When I use that code (and modify it to suit my needs) and open the page, it doesn't convert it to links, and when I view source, It hasn't changed to something like the second code snippet.

Comment: @MCAdventureCity can you please share the code you wrote?